# validar TextChange funcion resta de numeros

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenos dias a todos, tengo que hacer un calculo (calcular el vuelto a entregar) entre un total y el efectivo entregado, estoy trabajando con valores decimales. La operación de calculo la esta realizando bien, ingreso los valores y autmaticamente me muestra el resultado en un label (hago uso del evento TextChanged del label, donde llamo a la funcion que hace el calculo) el tema es que cuando borro alguno de los valores den los textbox, el programa se cae y me muestra este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obviamente, lo que necesito es validar que cuando se borren los valores, no se gatille el evento que hace el calculo, pero no me doy una idea como hacerlo,había intentado con comprobar los campos vacíos, pero no me resulto (ver en imagen el código que estaba probando).

Agradezco desde ya sus comentarios, saludos a todos.

Metodo para ahcer el calculo:

```
private void calcularVuelto()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMontoCancelar.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEfectivo.Text))
        {
            this.txtMontoCancelar.Text = "00.000";
            this.txtEfectivo.Text = "00.000";
        }
        else
        {
            total = decimal.Parse(this.txtMontoCancelar.Text);
            efectivo = decimal.Parse(this.txtEfectivo.Text);             
            vuelto = total - efectivo;
            //txtVuelto.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(vuelto).ToString();
            lblVuelto.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(vuelto).ToString();
        }           
    }
```

y en el evento leave del label donde muestro el resultado:

this.calcularVuelto();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que pude ver por tu método debes asignar el evento **TextChanged** a los **TextBox** luego de eso en cada función debes invocar el método **calcularVuelto();** puede ser de la siguiente manera:

**OnlyDecimales_KeyPress** se lo asignarías al **KeyPress** de cada **TextBox**

```
decimal total;
decimal efectivo;
decimal vuelto;

private void OnlyDecimales_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.')) || ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1));
}

private void txtMontoCancelar_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calcularVuelto();
}

private void txtEfectivo_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calcularVuelto();
}

private void calcularVuelto()
{
    txtMontoCancelar.Text = decimal.TryParse(txtMontoCancelar.Text.Replace('.', ','), out total) ? total.ToString() : "0";
    txtEfectivo.Text = decimal.TryParse(txtEfectivo.Text.Replace('.', ','), out efectivo) ? efectivo.ToString() : "0";
    vuelto = total - efectivo;
    lblVuelto.Text = string.Format("{0:00.000}", vuelto);
}
```

Comment: hola @Victor Perdomo, gracias por tu tiempo, me falla igual, borro el efectivo y si quiero borrar el monto ingresado, se cae el programa

Comment: Por favor agrega el metodo TextChanged y el de Validación para ayudarte mejor. Copialo y pegalo aqui en la pregunta. Además valida que solo se puedan ingresar números, puntos y comas.

Comment: listo, añadi el codigo de la funcion, en el evento LEAVE es donde llamo a la funcion para calcular

Comment: Listo, ya puedes probar me comentas si te funciono

Comment: Gracias victor, funciono bastante bien...

Comment: De nada amigo éxitos con tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente.

```
if(txtMontoCancelar.Text == "" || txtEfectivo.Text == "")
```

Espero te ayude.